# Can't run node project after formatting my linux partition

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb

As the title says, I formatted my linux partition where I used as web development environment. Mainly I used MongoDB and NodeJS and both of them are installed correctly. But when I try to execute my main.js I get an error log. It must be something extremely silly that I'm not reminded of. Any help is appreciated. Error log:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Note that **helpers.js** is a [node internal module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js#L20).

Comment: What do you have in `helpers.js` on line `20`?

Comment: I wish I knew. I never even touched these files. But that is because that is probably a native nodeJS file that I don't even know where its located exactly

Comment: This actually looks like an incompatibility between Node v9, and v10. If you check your node version, `node -v`, I assume you are probably running 10+?

Comment: See [this thread](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/issues/1830).

Comment: Yes I'm running 10.8.0

Comment: It actually looks like the [helpers.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js#L17) file has a method definition for `require`, and the line that is failing, `return mod.require(path);`, seems to actually be doing so, because `require` is supposed to be a reserved keyword...

Comment: What do you recommend? Maybe removing Node and installing a different version?

Comment: I have something like 5 or 10 projects and they all give +- the same error log

Comment: Yep, definitely seems to be an issue between some library versions. Yeah, maybe try installing an older version of node? [Others seem to have similar issues](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21995).

Comment: With previous versions I get another log:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bruno/Desktop/Dev/Dev/Auth/AuthDemo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:20:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:35

Answer (score -1):

Please download nodeJS command prompt for Linux or download by command

> pacman -S nodejs npm

For More help : Visit the link
[Node JS Installation Guide](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)